# The cell is filled with $0,00 but IF(Cell >0;True;False) return True

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, when I compare a Cell filled with `$0,00` using:

```
CELL [$0,00]

IF(Cell > 0; true; false).
```

It returns `true`, but Cell is = 0. It should return `false`.

It seems to be related to floating point. What can I do to IF consider $0,00 equal to 0?

P.S. I did the same formula in another Google sheet but there the sheet consider $0,00 equal to 0 and return `false`.

Comment: is the $0,00 result of something? can you share a copy of your sheet? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bezHk.png

Comment: yes, the cell is an result. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13a6LY8-Yer77vRe0PA44UGXOw4EBzERAJ5zhpW3oa0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I take a value ($) and I decompose it in groupes of quotes.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

- in terms of currency it's safe to introduce a small fix with **`ROUNDDOWN`** formula to ensure that **$0.001** of the cent is considered as **$0.00**

  [image: 0]